# trying to find the fixed points, stability, and then trying to see what it converges to.

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

In the following question I am trying to find the fixed points, stability, and then trying to see what it converges to.

To find the stability of this we must find $|f'(x^*)|$ to see whether it is $>1$ which would make it unstable or $<1$ which would make it stable.

$x_{n+1}=lnx_n$

So setting $f(x)=lnx$ and $f(x)=x$ to find the fixed point then $x=lnx$

But how do I find the value of this $x$ that makes $x=lnx$ work. You cant use $x=1$ because $1\ne 0$. I am not trying to use a graphical method either, trying to work it out numerically.

Once I have the fixed points, I could then use $|f'(x^*)|$ to find out whether $|f'(x^*)|<1$ to make it stable or whether $|f'(x^*)|>1$ which makes it unstable.

Are there any intersection points?

Comment: The tools you are trying to use are spectacularly *not* adapted to the question. To wit, the sequence $(x_n)$ you wish to study is defined by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ for $f(x)=\ln x$, presumably with $x_0>0$. Now, $f(x)$ is undefined if $x\leqslant0$ and $f(x)\leqslant x-1$ for every $x>0$ hence $x_n\leqslant x_0-n$ for every $n$ such that $x_n$ exists, and after a while $0\leqslant x_n<1$ hence $x_{n+1}$ does not exist. To sum up, there is no fixed point and, even, there is no initial condition $x_0$ such that the whole sequence $(x_n)$ is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let us rewrite the equation $x = \ln x$ satisfied by the stationnary points as
$$ {-1} = {-\ln x}\, \text{e}^{-\ln x} \, , $$
which is of the form $X \text{e}^{X}= Y$ with $X={-\ln x}$ and $Y={-1}$. The solutions are $X=W (Y)$, where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Hence,
$$ x = \text{e}^{-W (-1)} = -W (-1) \, . $$
This value is not real, since the natural logarithm $x\mapsto \ln x$ and the identity $x\mapsto x$ don't cross on the real line.

When studying the present dynamical system, one can observe that $x_{n+1} = \ln x_n \leq x_n -1$. The sequence $x_{n+1}= x_n -1$ is strictly decreasing with no limit, and so does $x_{n+1} = \ln x_n$ (until $x_n \leq 0$ for some $n$, where $x_{n+1}$ becomes complex).

Comment: so there are not fixed are no fixed points then?

Comment: so then how would I evaluate at stability using $|f'(x^*)|$ with $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$